# Is it possible to have 1 query instead of 2 queries for the below mentioned case?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I have two tables in Postgresql as below:

1. receipt

   ```
   id CHARACTER VARYING(20),
   account CHARACTER VARYING(20),
   date DATE,
   amount NUMERIC(8,2),
   PRIMARY KEY(id)
   ```
2. non_cash

   ```
   id CHARACTER VARYING(20),
   account CHARACTER VARYING(20),
   date DATE,
   amount NUMERIC(8,2),
   PRIMARY KEY(id)
   ```

Now I want to select the `SUM(amount)` from both the tables where `account = '00210_pre'` and `SUM(amount)` and `MAX(date)` from both the tables where `account = '00210_int'`. I am able to get the desired result using 2 queries as:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) AS int_total, MAX(date)
FROM (SELECT amount, date, account FROM non_cash
UNION SELECT amount, date, account FROM receipts) AS v
WHERE account = '00210_int'
```

and

```
SELECT SUM(amount) AS pre_total
FROM (SELECT amount, account FROM non_cash
UNION SELECT amount, account FROM receipts) AS v
WHERE account = '00210_pre'
```

Now My question is **Is it possible to have the above in just one query? If yes how?**

Kindly note that the account only varies in the suffix as *_pre* and *_int* the rest numbers are same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use `UNION`.  You should use `UNION ALL`, because `UNION` removes duplicates, which is probably not desirable and is a waste of effort.  But, the answer to your question is `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT account, SUM(amount) AS int_total, MAX(date)
FROM ((SELECT amount, date, account FROM non_cash
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT amount, date, account FROM receipts)
     ) v
WHERE account IN ('00210_int', '00210_pre')
GROUP BY account;
```

Note:  if you want the values combined, then don't use the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) AS int_total, MAX(date)
FROM ((SELECT amount, date, account FROM non_cash
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT amount, date, account FROM receipts)
     ) v
WHERE account IN ('00210_int', '00210_pre');
```

EDIT:

To get a single row use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN account = '00210_int' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS int_total,
       SUM(CASE WHEN account = '00210_pre' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS pre_total,
       MAX(date)
FROM ((SELECT amount, date, account FROM non_cash
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT amount, date, account FROM receipts)
     ) v
WHERE account IN ('00210_int', '00210_pre');
```

Comment: i want separate sum for  '00210_int' and '00210_pre' as int_total and pre_total respectivey

Comment: @Blip . . . That is the first query in the answer.

Comment: OK, But is it possible to return it as a single row?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT left(nc.account,5) account, 
    max(greatest(nc.date, r.date)) max_date,
    sum(nc.amount + r.amount) total
    sum(CASE WHEN nc.account = '00210_int' OR r.account = '00210_int' THEN 
            nc.amount + r.amount
            ELSE NULL
            END
            ) int_total,
    sum(CASE WHEN nc.account = '00210_pre' OR r.account = '00210_pre' THEN 
            nc.amount + r.amount
            ELSE NULL
            END
            ) pre_total
FROM non_cash nc
INNER JOIN receipts r
ON left(nc.account,5) = left(r.account,5)
WHERE nc.account  IN ( '00210_int', '00210_pre')
OR r.account  IN ( '00210_int', '00210_pre')
GROUP BY 1
```

Comment: both non_cash and receipts have values '00210_int' and '00210_pre'. Also i want separate `int_total` and `pre_total` respectively from both these tables.

Comment: You have edited your query but int_total will give the sum of all the rows of non_cash where account is '00210_int' or '00210_pre' and int_total will give the sum of all the rows of receipts where account is  '00210_int' or '00210_pre' but what I wanted was int_total should be the sum of all the rows in both non_cash and receipt tables where account = '00210_int' and pre_total should be the sum of all the rows in both non_cash and receipt tables where account = '00210_pre'

Comment: @blip ok, you made me break down and use a conditional. :)